# iOS: Text translation from English to different language and vice-versa

Tags: ipad, ios5, multilingual, google-translate

I want to translate English texts to different languages from my iPad App. These texts are generated dynamically from the front end website so I can use static mapping between English and other language. Basically I will receive line of text in English from the server and I want to convert it to iPad's Locale language settings and display it. Is there anyone I can achieve this? Can I use Google translator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Translate provides a really neat API that you can use to quickly and easily use in your apps to translate text between tons of different languages. here is the good tutorial :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone